# How can I trigger a function when a webpage is successfully loaded in webview?

Tags: android, webview

I want to trigger a function after webview's finished loading a webpage and received no error. According to my experiment, the onPageFinished() will be triggered several times and in most of the cases, it will be executed before onReceivedError().

So how can I know that the webpage is loaded and no error is received?

Comment: Having a listener with `WebView.setWebChromeClient` and overriding `onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress)` with waiting for `newProgress==100` is an alternative way for listening to load finished...

Comment: Is this newProgress == 100 guaranteed to occur only once and after onReceivedError?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `WebViewClient` in the `WebView` and Override its Callback methods which will let you know when the webpage has finished loading the page. For example

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


    @Override
    public void  onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        if(progess!=null){
            progess.dismiss();

        }
        progess = ProgressDialog.show(LoadUrl.this, "", "Loading please wait...");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("callback")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs

        view.loadUrl(url);
       return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        // Add YOUR CODE HERE 
    }

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
     Toast.makeText(LoadUrl.this, "Sorry! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

    @Override
 public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
     super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
     handler.proceed(); 


 }
}
```

Here `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` will be called when webView has finished loading the current Page.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your codes, it helps me resolved some of the questing. But unfortunately, I found that this onPageFinished() function will also be triggered at least twice. Is there any method that can ensure that it will be called only once?

Comment: No there is no such method which can ensure that it is called once the thing you can do is set a bool variable and depending upon its value write your code.